# Laravel Return List of Items From Table

Tags: laravel

Seems like this should be a simple question, but I'm not getting it. I have a table called "following" with columns 'user_id' and 'following_id'. I am trying to return a list of values from the user_id column where the corresponding following_id column contains a certain value (in this case it's 1). See code below.

```
public function showFollowers()
{
    $users = DB::table('following')->where('following_id',1)->lists('user_id');
}
```

Then, in my view is have

```
@if (!$user->showFollowers())
    You have no followers.
@else
    @foreach ($user->showFollowers() as $user)
        <p class="username">{{ $user->getUsername() }}</p>
        <a href="{{ route('profile', ['username' => $user->username]) }}"></a>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

I'm not getting anything though, and no errors so the query must be correct. I must not be looping correctly in my view...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the value of the function.  Try:

```
public function showFollowers()
{
    return DB::table('following')->where('following_id',1)->lists('user_id');
}
```

Comment: Throws error "trying to get property of non-object". I know it returns an array, but I'm not grabbing those values correctly...hmm...

Comment: What is the code in the foreach loop?  The list returns an array of IDs, not users, so if you are trying to get a property of `$user` it would give that error.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out, because the loop contains the name and a route to a view with that user's info. The edit above has the loop code. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it! Please accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Haha, sorry, no I'm still figuring it out. My thought is I need to create a new function that takes that ID from the array and returns the username from the users table. Right? Thanks.

Comment: does followers refer to other user models?

Comment: It doesn't. It might help to post the whole issue...since Stack won't let me post again for 90 minutes. Please see this laracasts discussion. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-many-to-many-relationship-loops?page=1#reply-120109